# Query in Laravel not working against created_at column

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I am writing a query in which I want to fetch data against `created_at` column. But its not working, it does not return anything. I am using Mongodb as database. Created_at column date is in the format `"created_at": ISODate("2016-05-11T09:29:33.112Z")` and when I fetch it from database it gives me 2016-05-11 09:29:33.

```
$datetimenow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data = ChatMessages::where('created_at','<',$datetimenow)->count();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, this is the way how I can do this.

```
$d1 = new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-01-04 23:21:46'));
$d2 = new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-05-09 23:21:46'));
$data = ChatMessages::whereRaw(['created_at' => array('$gt' => $d1, '$lt' => $d2)])->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Carbon Package

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now('Asia/Dubai'); //you can specify your own timezone
$messages = ChatMessages::where('created_at', '<', $now)->get();
dd($messages);
```